# how to show the line number in the text editor of Dymola?

Tags: dymola

In dymola, the error message would use the line number to show the source of error, but the text editor didn't show the line number, how could I enable this functionality in dymola?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dymola displays the current line number in the status bar in the lower right corner.

Until Dymola 2019 it looked as follows:

[image: line number in dymola status bar]

Since Dymola 2020x (ribbon interface) it looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, it is not possible to show numbers beside each code line.

You can also use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to jump to a certain line number.